# What could be the reason to not be able to use Math built-in functions in OpenCL? Should I use some directive to active?

Tags: opencl

The build returns -11 error. Removing pow function compiles fine. I'm not using embedded profile.

```
__kernel void VectorAdd(__global int* a)
{
    unsigned int n = get_global_id(0);
    a[n] = pow(2, 2); 
}
```

Im catching the error but the string is empty

```
int err = clBuildProgram(OpenCLProgram, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS)  
{ 
    size_t len;  
    char buffer[2048];                  
    printf("Error: Failed to build program executable!\n");
    clGetProgramBuildInfo(OpenCLProgram, cdDevice, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), buffer, &len);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    exit(1);
}
```

Some useful info:
CL_DEVICE_NAME: AMD Radeon HD - FirePro D300 Compute Engine
CL_DRIVER_VERSION: 1.2 (Jan 10 2017 22:25:08)

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [OpenCL documentation for pow](http://man.opencl.org) you will notice that it is defined as `gentype pow(gentype x, gentype y)`. The document also states that

> The generic type name gentype is used to indicate that the function can take float, float2, float3, float4, float8, float16, double, double2, double3, double4, double8, or double16 as the type for the arguments.

So `pow()` takes two `float` or two `double` values or vectors thereof and returns a value of the same type. Since the compiler cannot determine wether you wanted to call `pow(2.0, 2.0)` (double precision) or `pow(2.0f, 2.0f)` (single precision), you get an error instead.

Note that there is also the similar-named function `float pown(float x, int y)` which takes an integer value for the exponent (e.g. `pown(2.0f, 2)`) and may provide an optimized implementation of this case.

Answer (score 0):

1. What does [clGetProgramBuildInfo()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetProgramBuildInfo.html) with *param_name*=`CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG` say? This should give you a much more detailed error message. Update the question with this and I might be able to expand this answer.
2. What version of OpenCL is this? Note that prior to 1.2, the `pow()` function was only defined for floating-point types; you're expecting it to work with integers.

Comment: The problem was with integers. I change to 2.0 and it's working. Can't be used with integers?

Comment: @Eduardo If your buildinfo string is empty, check the required length and dynamically allocate the buffer. The 2048 byte buffer may not be large enough.

Comment: There are different versions of pow, if your exponent is integer you could use `pown()` but first argument needs to be floating point value.